# IBM Worklight session control with back-end server

Tags: session, architecture, ibm-mobilefirst

Got a question on IBM worklight server, thanks in advance for any comments on this subject.

### Workflow:

User --> WorkLight Server --> Back-end Server

### Scenario:

(1) Designed a mobile application with IBM worklight studio and deployed to worklight server.

(2) Must use worklight server for the first entry point (user authentication by LDAP via worklight server)

(3) This mobile application designed for downloading/uploading huge file size (10mb to 1gb) to the backend server behind the worklight server (refer to the workflow pls.)

### Question(s):

(1) How session sharing can be done in between worklight server and the back-end server?

(2) If session sharing cannot be done, what's the safest way that mobile application download/upload the files to the back-end server given that the application and back-end server do not know its the same authenticated transaction by skipping worklight server?

(3) Did I misunderstood anything from the worklight server architecture? as far as I know worklight server is just kind of gateway and presentation layer for deploying mobile application by its framework. Heavy and complex computation logic should be handled by other backend server. As long as the worklight server network IO is wide enough for file transfer, it shouldn't be a problem for the worklight server act as a gateway in this case. For file transfer, it shouldn't be a burden for CPU for computation as it is just simply in and out from the user device to the backend server (worklight as a middle man).

Thank you and sorry for the lengthy question.

Answer (score 2):

**(1) How session sharing can be done in between worklight server and the back-end server?**

Can I make the assumption that you will be using a worklight adapter in order to do your file transfers? In that case, a "session" between the adapter and the client will be created. To be a bit more specific, if I have a global variable stored in my adapter and I modify the variable based on the adapter call from the client, the state of the variable will be maintained upon subsequent requests, and the state of that variable will only be visible to the calling client. (Just a note, this is not always true in clustered environments, where the client may be calling adapters on separate worklight servers)

**(2) If session sharing cannot be done, what's the safest way that mobile application download/upload the files to the back-end server given that the application and back-end server do not know its the same authenticated transaction by skipping worklight server?**

As stated above, this can be achieved through adapters. Since adapters can be protected through authentication, it knows that the client is calling through the same authenticated transaction.

**(3) Did I misunderstood anything from the worklight server architecture? as far as I know worklight server is just kind of gateway and presentation layer for deploying mobile application by its framework. Heavy and complex computation logic should be handled by other backend server. As long as the worklight server network IO is wide enough for file transfer, it shouldn't be a problem for the worklight server act as a gateway in this case. For file transfer, it shouldn't be a burden for CPU for computation as it is just simply in and out from the user device to the backend server (worklight as a middle man).**

You hit the nail on the head. I haven't personally done any performance testing with a high amount of computations on the worklight server, but if it is being used simply as a passthrough then you should be fine. The worklight server has been known to be able to process a relatively high amount of concurrent adapter calls, so I believe you will be fine with your setup.